# Blender Model and Animation Deformed when Exported for Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I am trying to export a model that I made in Blender, so I can use it in a Three.JS project. I have attempted to use both Blender 2.8 GLTF Exporter that comes with 2.8, and Blender 2.79 GLTF Blender IO exporter. Both end up with a similar outcome, depending on what settings I choose when I export.

When I choose "Skinning" as an export option, my animation (Gallop) is applied but my model is deformed. (See pic)

In Blender, I use a simple armature made up of bones, and animate over 20 frames. Nothing crazy, but I'm unsure if there is anything I need to do in Blender before exported to ensure the animation/model remain in tact.

To note, the horse's saddle and pad are separate objects, which I have parented under my Horse armature. I did this because I wanted them to move slightly when the horse gallop animation occurs.

I've attached a few screenshots and my blend file is below. Does anyone have any suggestions to help me get this model exported correctly? (At this point, just getting it to work in the [GLTF Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) is enough)

[Horse Blend File](http://www.thefarmventures.com/images/horseNew.blend)

[image: Blender view]

[image: Horse model in GLTF Viewer]

Comment: Um, it seems the link to your `blend` file is dead...

Comment: It is working for me (Chrome), but here is a link to a zip of the blend file. http://www.thefarmventures.com/images/horseNew.blend.zip

Comment: I've exported from Blender 2.8 as `glTF` (with default settings) and imported it into https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/. Everything looks fine. Can you try it with a fresh installation of Blender 2.8?

Comment: I was able to export it correctly (mostly) by clicking on the mesh in object mode, then pressing ctrl+a and clicking location, rotation and scale (for the horse, saddle and pad). This has worked mostly, and also shown me that I need a lot of clean-up in my mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sort of distortion happens when the location of the armature and mesh are different.

In blender select all and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*->Rotation & Scale*

You will find that the saddle and blanket won't be positioned properly, you should add an armature modifier to them so that they follow along with the horse. This would be due to blender using z-up and exporting to a y-up environment (the y-up conversion is an option when exporting).

Comment: Great, in my case, I needed to select the horse mesh and reset the location. It works now, thanks! I will take a look at armature modifiers for the saddle and blanket. This is my first model, so it's a bit rough, I wish the saddle blanket would drape a bit more like cloth, but not sure how to do that and export it.